# Referencing governmental organization in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex

I want to cite a company (governmental organization) as a reference.

The organization name is : "*MeteoSwiss*"
 under the control of "*Federal Department of Home Affairs FDHA
Federal Office of Meteorology and Climatology MeteoSwiss*"

Plz help me how I can create the format in LaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you edit your question so that it shows what citation style you are using or post a picture that shows what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @hpesoj626 I am using APA in latex from natbib package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even webpage of the organization can be presented by :

```
@misc{r33,
  author = {SensoreScope},
  howpublished = "\url{http://lcav.epfl.ch/op/edit/sensorscope-en/}",
  year = {2007}, 
  note = "[Online; accessed  2013/01/10]"
}
```

OR:

```
@misc{r32,
  author={MeteoSwiss},
  publisher={Federal Department of Home Affairs FDHA Federal Office of Meteorology and Climatology MeteoSwiss}
}
```